# Error 'java.lang.String com.example.bookretrofit.Imagelink.getSmallThumbnail()' on a null object reference using Glide

Tags: android-studio, if-statement, retrofit, android-glide

Logcat error ( it was not able to handle null exception in glide when no image is found). I wasn't able to put if/else statement.

```
2020-11-19 10:46:27.887 9386-9386/com.example.bookretrofit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.bookretrofit, PID: 9386
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.bookretrofit.Imagelink.getSmallThumbnail()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.bookretrofit.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:56)
    at com.example.bookretrofit.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:19)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:288)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:345)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:361)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:368)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:399)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7548)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

RecyclerViewAdapter

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int i) {

    VolumeInfo volumeInfo = this.volumeInfo.get(i).getVolumeInfo();
    holder.tvTitle.setText(volumeInfo.getTitle());
    if (volumeInfo.getAuthors() != null && !volumeInfo.getAuthors().isEmpty()) {
        holder.tvAuthor.setText(volumeInfo.getAuthors().get(0));
    } else  {
        holder.tvAuthor.setText("NO AUTHOR");
    }
    Glide.with(mContext).load(volumeInfo.getImageLinks().getSmallThumbnail()).into(holder.ivThumbnail);
```

I want to return a default image from Drawable if the image load is null. How can I do it with if/else statement. This part of the code is creating all the problem

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(volumeInfo.getImageLinks().getSmallThumbnail()).into(holder.ivThumbnail);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the stacktrace I suppose you could simply do

```java
if (volumeInfo.getImageLinks() == null) {
   holder.ivThumbnail.setImageDrawable(null);
} else {
 Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(volumeInfo.getImageLinks()
          .getSmallThumbnail())
          .into(holder.ivThumbnail);
}
```

Seems like `volumeInfo.getImageLinks()` is null.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, the error is gone . I have one more question for you.. How to display a image from drawable when then is no image found. How to implement the code in this part  holder.ivThumbnail.setImageDrawable(null)  @Fred

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. What part of the code do you need? Reading something from the resource folders?

Comment: Haha don't be afraid. Okay let me explain you again. In (RecyclerViewAdapter) code i checked for Author name if the Author name is present or not using if/else statement.. if it is present in the url then it set the text of author name but if it is not present then it show "NO AUTHOR" . At the same way in Glide we put if/else statement.. if the image url is found it will set the image but if the image url is null then i want to set a default image from drawable folder instead of just blank screen because in my app when there is no image found it showed blank imageview @Fred

Comment: Are you talking about `holder.ivThumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.whatever_you_named_your_img)`?

Comment: Yeah yeah that's what i was talking about . How to put default image there instead of null because when i wrote  `holder.ivThumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.whatever_you_named_your_img)` then i got error that - ` Required type: Drawable  ,      Provided: int `   @Fred

Comment: It's a different method. It's not `setImageDrawable` but `setImageResource`.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Now it's working without any error. Because of your help i was able to handle this error and learned something new . Thank you so much for giving your time and helped me  @Fred